# Python BeautifulSoup failure to get data from a div with a certain class

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a program that will scrape metacritic for info on the movie from my library and display it but in certain parts like grabbing the rating always returns nothing what am I doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

def ratingsGet(headers, movie):
    movie = movie.lower().replace(" ","-")
    detail_link="https://www.metacritic.com/movie/" + movie + "/details"
    detail_page = requests.get(detail_link, headers = headers) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(detail_page.content, "html.parser")
    #g_data = soup.select('tr.movie_rating td.data span')
    g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "movie_rating"})
    print(g_data)

    if g_data!= []:
        return g_data[0].text
    else:
        return "Failed"

def getMovieInfo():
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_0) AppleWebKit/536.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.849.0 Safari/536.1'}
    
    for movie in os.listdir("D:/Movies/"):
        movie = movie.lower().replace(".mp4","")
        print(movie)
        print("Rating: " + ratingsGet(headers,movie))
        print("Home release year: " + rYearGet(headers,movie))
        break
```

html snippet:

```
<table class="details" summary="13 Going on 30 Details and Credits">
<tr class="runtime">
<td class="label">Runtime:</td>
<td class="data">98 min</td>
</tr>
<tr class="movie_rating">
<td class="label">Rating:</td>
<td class="data">
                                                                            Rated PG-13 for some sexual content and brief drug references.
                                                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="company">
<td class="label">Production:</td>
<td class="data">Revolution Studios</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is not a answer but, why are you using `find_all` and then returning only the first element text? I believe you can use `find` directly.

Comment: @JorgeMorgado It is returning nothing at all.

Comment: On the other hand, did you check the resulting html from `requests.get`?, can you put the html in the question?

Comment: Did you check that the movies inside the `D:/Movies/` folder has the same name as in the link?

Comment: @JorgeMorgado I added a html snippet from the website and yes I have verrified the link that it is showing is working in this isntance https://www.metacritic.com/movie/13-going-on-30/details

Comment: I see, and what you want is th "Rated PG-13 for some sexual content and brief drug references." text, am I right?

Comment: @JorgeMorgado nvm I am just stupid I had a div as search not tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you need to look for a "tr" (not a "div"). I will also append to the answer this.

- Try to use only `find` (no need of find all)
- If the result of `find` is not None, do another find in it to get only the text, like this:

```py
g_data.find("td", { "class": "data" }).text
```

The genral code will be something like this:

```py
def ratingsGet(headers, movie):
    movie = movie.lower().replace(" ","-")
    detail_link="https://www.metacritic.com/movie/" + movie + "/details"
    detail_page = requests.get(detail_link, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(detail_page.content, "html.parser")
    g_data = soup.find("tr", {"class": "movie_rating"})

    # Check if that tr exists
    if g_data is not None:
        g_data = g_data.find("td", { "class": "data" })

    # Check if the td inside of it exists
    if g_data is not None:
        return g_data.text.strip()
    return "Failed"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just searching for the wrong element....

```
def ratingsGet(headers, movie):
    movie = movie.lower().replace(" ","-")
    detail_link="https://www.metacritic.com/movie/" + movie + "/details"
    detail_page = requests.get(detail_link, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(detail_page.content, "html.parser")
    #g_data = soup.select('tr.movie_rating td.data span')
    g_data = soup.find_all("tr", {"class": "movie_rating"})
    print(g_data[0].text.strip(" "))
    
    if g_data!= []:
        return g_data[0].text
    else:
        return "Failed"
```

Comment: This might still not give you the exact text I think

Comment: @JorgeMorgado So it does but it has some really weird spacing lol

Comment: Well I wrote an answer, hope it helps. Few annotations: use find (this will stop looking whe the first match occours), also, `strip` by default removes the initial and final spaces (no need to pass `" "`), and final, if an `if` statement will always return you don't nees to write the `else` statement